# java-wrapper-1.1.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar conflicts with newer httpcore-4.4.5.jar?

Tags: exception, classpath, websphere-liberty, ibm-watson

I'm getting an odd error that seems to point to httpcore conflicts. While I have only one httpcore-4.4.5.jar in the classpath, I also have the java-wrapper-1.1.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar for Watson services access. It seems to carry a bunch of Apache http* classes. Is there a newer version of the java-wrapper.jar that is compatible with the newer Apache jar files? The error in the Liberty 16.0.0.4 ffdc file is: Stack Dump = java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:144)

I suppose I can overwrite the classes in the java-wrapper jar file with newer versions but was hoping this had been done already.

Comment: Because I had access to all the needed versions of the apache classes, removing all the org.apache packaged classes from the java-wrapper jar file solved the problem. The error message is a far cry from helping explain the problem, but luckily it is well documented on the internet. I'd added this because one may not realize the embedded org.apache classes in the Watson sdk jar helper file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by removing org.apache packaged classes from the java-wrapper jar file and using the proper versions of the http*.jar files from the Apache website instead.